# Compilation error with flex and lex.yy.cc on MacOS

Tags: macos, flex-lexer, lexer

I have written a flex file and using the flex command to create lex.yy.cc. When I try to run the lex.yy.cc to create the lexer it gives me and error from lex.yy.cc.

```
error: out-of-line definition of 'LexerInput' does not match any declaration in 'yyFlexLexer'
error: out-of-line definition of 'LexerOutput' does not match any declaration in 'yyFlexLexer'
```

I am confused why there are errors in the lex.yy.cc file that is generated using the flex command. The commands I ran in terminal are

```
flex++ test.flex
g++ lex.yy.cc
```

I recently installed flex so it should be up to date. The version is 2.6.4.
Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Can you share the generated source code? Or create a minimal example?

Answer (score 1):

A bit of Googling suggests this can happen on MacOS when there are conflicting versions of Flex installed (from MacPorts and the system version).

See for example: https://bugs.launchpad.net/zorba/+bug/1034582

Apparently the easiest solution is to uninstall the MacPorts version.

Comment: Do you mean uninstall the MacPorts version? I already had the MacPorts version installed now I uninstalled it. My current flex is in /usr/bin/ is that the system version? After I uninstalled it, there are new errors occuring. 'undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "yylex()", referenced from _main in lex-6472d0.o'

Comment: I have had arm64 errors before in XCode and I was able to fix it by going into the project settings but here I am using the terminal instead of XCode how would I address this issue?

Comment: @chickennuggies: yes, I meant uninstall.

To fix the linker errors: you might have to add `-lfl` to the compiler flags.

Comment: It says 'library not found: -lfl' I have tried looking for libfl.a on the system and have no success. Does anyone know if the system version of flex does not come with libfl.a? Or is it under a different name

Comment: Google suggests the right flag on Mac OS is `-ll` instead. I'm not a Mac user so I don't know why it's different. If that doesn't solve your problem, try opening a new question with source code, the compiler invocation, and the full error message you get.